# SDL Tridion Publishing - Data not going to broker DB

Tags: 2011, 2013-sp1, publishing, upgrade

I am trying to update the Tridion 2011 Sp1 to Tridion 2013 Sp1 with legacy visible = True as we only want to upgrade CMS not the content delivery DD4T version. That's why I am trying with Legacy option.

I have successfully upgraded the Tridion_Broker and Tridion_CM databases with the upgrade scripts.
I have installed the SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 with the upgarded databases. However i have CM and Databases on different servers.

I am facing issues with the publishing to Broker DB. Dynamic content and pages are not going to Tridion_Broker DB. 
I checked the publishing with a demo page with DWT Templates and its working fine and page is getting published to filesystem.
Also I am getting success status everytime I do the publishing with DD4T page.

One more thing I created a new publication in CMS to check the connectivity between the CMS server and Database server and I am able to create publication in CMS and Publication Data is going in Tridion_CM database.

Currently deployer log is not getting generated but I am attaching the old deployer log for some reference.

> 2016-02-29 15:54:27,554 INFO  Deployer - ********************************************************************************
>   2016-02-29 15:54:27,554 INFO  Deployer - 
>   2016-02-29 15:54:27,928 INFO  Deployer - Configuration: cd_deployer_conf.xml xslt has run
>   2016-02-29 15:54:27,990 INFO  ProcessorFactory - Adding Processor Configuration:Processor(Action=Deploy, Class=com.tridion.deployer.Processor)[A Module is triggered by a Processor to process incoming instructions.
>                       The 'Type' attribute needs to be unique within a Processor and serves
>                       as a symbolic identifier. The 'Class' attribute defines the
>                       implementation used for any type of Module. Replace or add modules to
>                       implement custom Deployer behavior.Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.SchemaDeploy, Type=SchemaDeploy), Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy, Type=PageDeploy)[The transformer enables the TCDL EngineTransformer(Class=com.tridion.deployer.TCDLTransformer)], Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.BinaryDeploy, Type=BinaryDeploy), Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentDeploy, Type=ComponentDeploy), Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.TemplateDeploy, Type=TemplateDeploy), Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.PublicationDeploy, Type=PublicationDeploy)This module enables deployment of taxonomies, Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyDeploy, Type=TaxonomyDeploy), Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationDeploy, Type=ComponentPresentationDeploy)[The transformer enables the TCDL EngineTransformer(Class=com.tridion.deployer.TCDLTransformer)]This module enables deployment of structure groups, Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupDeploy, Type=StructureGroupDeploy)This module enables the deploy of extension data. This module should be enabled if you are using UNDO]
>   2016-02-29 15:54:27,990 INFO  ProcessorFactory - Adding Processor Configuration:Processor(Action=Undeploy, Class=com.tridion.deployer.Processor)[Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageUndeploy, Type=PageUndeploy), Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationUndeploy, Type=ComponentPresentationUndeploy)This module enables the undeploy of taxonomies, Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyUndeploy, Type=TaxonomyUndeploy)This module enables the undeploy of structure groups, Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupUndeploy, Type=StructureGroupUndeploy)This module enables the undeploy of extension data. This module should be enabled if you are using UNDO]
>   2016-02-29 15:54:28,006 INFO  QueueLocationHandler - Maximum number of retries configured is 10
>   2016-02-29 15:54:28,006 INFO  QueueLocationHandler - Writing deployer window size: c:\tridion\incoming\meta.xml.
>   2016-02-29 15:54:28,006 INFO  QueueLocationHandler - Maximum number of retries configured is 10
>   2016-02-29 15:54:28,006 INFO  QueueLocationHandler - Writing deployer window size: c:\tridion\incoming\meta.xml.
>   2016-02-29 15:54:28,037 INFO  Deployer - Starting Deployer
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,050 INFO  ContentLocationHandler - Found 1 new packages for processing in c:\tridion\incoming
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,050 INFO  QueueLocationHandler - Retrieved Deployment package from queue with transactionId: tcm:0-274951-66560 and type: CONTENT
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,050 INFO  QueueLocationHandler - Starting running transaction thread: tcm:0-274951-66560
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,050 INFO  TransactionManager - Starting handling of Deployment package: tcm:0-274951-66560 with type: CONTENT
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,347 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Starting executing deployment pipeline for: tcm:0-274951-66560
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,347 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Executing deployment phase: Deployer Prepare Phase for transaction: tcm:0-274951-66560
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,362 INFO  UnzipWorker - Starting unzipping for transaction: tcm:0-274951-66560 and package: c:\tridion\incoming\tcm_0-274951-66560.Content.zip
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,393 INFO  UnzipWorker - Moving Deployment Package to unzip folder for transactionId: tcm:0-274951-66560
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,393 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Executing deployment phase: Deployment Processing Phase for transaction: tcm:0-274951-66560
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,487 INFO  ProcessingPhase - Starting executing of phase: PRE_PROCESSING for transaction: tcm:0-274951-66560
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,487 INFO  ProcessorFactory - Creating processors for phase: pre-processing
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,487 INFO  ProcessingPhase - Starting executing of phase: PROCESSING for transaction: tcm:0-274951-66560
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,487 INFO  ProcessorFactory - Creating processors for phase: processing
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,487 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.SchemaDeploy
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,502 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.BinaryDeploy
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,518 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentDeploy
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,518 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.TemplateDeploy
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,533 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.PublicationDeploy
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,533 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyDeploy
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,549 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupDeploy
>   2016-02-29 15:54:30,549 INFO  Processor - Modules will now process package [TransportPackage transactionId=tcm:0-274951-66560]
>   2016-02-29 15:54:32,889 INFO  Processor - All modules successfully processed package [TransportPackage transactionId=tcm:0-274951-66560]
>   2016-02-29 15:54:32,889 INFO  ProcessingPhase - Starting executing of phase: POST_PROCESSING for transaction: tcm:0-274951-66560
>   2016-02-29 15:54:32,889 INFO  ProcessorFactory - Creating processors for phase: post-processing
>   2016-02-29 15:54:32,889 INFO  ProcessingPhase - We have 12 transaction items waiting for commit.
>   2016-02-29 15:54:32,889 INFO  ProcessingPhase - Persisting transaction log for transaction: tcm:0-274951-66560.
>   2016-02-29 15:54:32,889 INFO  TransactionPersistence - Persisting deployment transaction information: tcm:0-274951-66560
>   2016-02-29 15:54:32,921 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Executing deployment phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase for transaction: tcm:0-274951-66560
>   2016-02-29 15:54:32,921 INFO  PreCommitPhase - Executing phase: pre-transaction for transaction: tcm:0-274951-66560
>   2016-02-29 15:54:32,921 INFO  ProcessorFactory - Creating processors for phase: pre-transaction
>   2016-02-29 15:54:32,921 INFO  TransactionPersistence - Loading deployment transaction information: tcm:0-274951-66560
>   2016-02-29 15:54:33,077 INFO  PreCommitPhase - Executing workers for transaction: tcm:0-274951-66560 with 12 Workers
>   2016-02-29 15:54:33,232 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Executing deployment phase: Deployment Commit Phase for transaction: tcm:0-274951-66560
>   2016-02-29 15:54:33,248 INFO  CommitPhase - Committing transaction: tcm:0-274951-66560
>   2016-02-29 15:54:33,310 INFO  TransactionPersistence - Removing deployment transaction information: tcm:0-274951-66560
>   2016-02-29 15:54:33,326 INFO  CommitPhase - Executing phase: post-transaction for transaction: tcm:0-274951-66560
>   2016-02-29 15:54:33,326 INFO  ProcessorFactory - Creating processors for phase: post-transaction
>   2016-02-29 15:54:33,326 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Transaction is completed: tcm:0-274951-66560
>   2016-02-29 15:54:33,326 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Finished executing deployment pipeline for: tcm:0-274951-66560 in 2979 ms.
>   2016-02-29 15:54:33,326 INFO  TransactionManager - Cleaning up Deployment package for transaction: tcm:0-274951-66560 and type: CONTENT
>   2016-02-29 15:54:33,342 INFO  TransactionManager - Finished handling of Deployment package: tcm:0-274951-66560 with type: CONTENT

About the settings, all settings are working on a different server where CMS, Content Delivery and Database are on the same server.

Need some urgent help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my storage config of deployer

```
        <Policy Type="LRU" Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy">

            <Param Name="MemSize" Value="16mb"/>
        </Policy>

        <Features>
            <Feature Type="DependencyTracker" Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker"/>
        </Features> 

    </ObjectCache>

    <Storages>
        <Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
            <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="10" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
            <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                <Property Name="serverName" Value="MYSQLServer" />
                <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
                <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker" />
                <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUserName" />
                <Property Name="password" Value="TridionBrokerPassword" />
            </DataSource>
        </Storage>

        <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
            <Root Path="C:\PublishedSite" />
        </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="filesystemDocRootPublicationId70">
            <Root Path="C:\Websites\dd4tmvcdemo" />
        </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="AspfilesystemPublicationId70">
            <Root Path="C:\Websites\dd4tmvcdemo" />
        </Storage>

    </Storages>

</Global>

<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
    <Item typeMapping="Query" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Publication" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="BinaryMeta" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="BinaryVariant" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="Category" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentMeta" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentationMeta" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="ItemMeta" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="CustomMeta" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Jsp" storageId="defaultFile" />
    <Item typeMapping="LinkInfo" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="PageMeta" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="Reference" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="Schema" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="Taxonomy" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="XSLT" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Txt" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="Timeframe" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="TrackedComponent" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="TrackedComponentLink" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="TrackedPage" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Xml" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="XSLT" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="Page" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="Personalization" storageId="defaultdb" />
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="defaultFile" />

    <Publication Id="70" defaultStorageId="defaultdb"> 
        <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="filesystemDocRootPublicationId70" />
    </Publication>
 </ItemTypes>

   <License Location="C:/Tridion/Licence/cd_licenses.xml"/>
```

Comment: please share you cd_storage config.

Comment: Thanks Raj for the reply. I have added the stogare config above.

Comment: do you have proper license, matching your machine name and cores? any logs?

Comment: Do you have the database drivers installed in your deployer server?

Comment: Legacy in CM is for VBscript support... You probably don't need that

Comment: Raj, I do have proper license files for CM and CD as well. If i do the publishing from another CM pointing to the same DB then its working fine.

Comment: Shiva, I have installed the proper drivers on database server as i have checked the publishing from different CM and its working fine in that scenario.

Comment: Nuno, Does the Legacy is only for VBscript support? I got to know that Legacy is to provide backward compatibility in Tridion versions. One more question is that can Legacy be responsible for my publishing issue? Thanks

Comment: can you try - defaultFilesystem="false" for each one of the File System type storage. specifically for: <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="filesystemDocRootPublicationId70">

Comment: Pankaj - I have tried this as well but it din't work for me.

Comment: When you say publish from different cms works,   does that also using same http upload instance which your problematic system is using.  If no worth to look logs of httpdployer of instance in debug /verbose mode

Comment: Hi Sumit, the log file is just showing that the package was picked up and processed. Perhaps you can enable hibernate logging, by adding the org.hibernate appender to the logback.xml.

Comment: Hi All,
As suggested by one of my senior colleague to cross verify the cd_license.xml file is correct or not, i requested a new cd_license.xml file for content delivery specifically and the issue got resolved by the new cd_license.xml file. So the issue was with cd_license.xml file. Thanks all for the guidance and responses.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to get the logging working to find the problem. In the meantime since this is a new scaled out configuration you should check that msdtc is configured on both servers and that firewall is configured.

Answer (score 0):

First, confirm your cd_licenses.xml file is correct and accessible from the Deployer.  The publish to Broker functionality is removed when a valid license is not found, but publishing to the filesystem still works.

Then, the Flow for your publishing is: Publisher -> Transport Service -> Deployer (Running as a Website in IIS with httpupload.aspx) -> Broker

Did you copy the Java MSSQL jdbc .jar file if you publish to SQL Server?

I'd suggest to open the logback.xml file in the Deployer/config folder and set it to DEBUG:

```
<property name="log.level" value="DEBUG"/>
```

Then make sure the Deployer site is configured in IIS, and you can open a web browser and access the URL.  I assume this works since you can publish to the filesystem.

Then restart the IIS Deployer and publish your Dynamic content.  You should have logging info in the new Deployer logs.

Please let us know what it was that fixes it.